# RPC header not found despite being installed

Tags: linux, arch-linux, makefile, configure, gis

I'm trying to install [MB-system](https://github.com/dwcaress/MB-System) on my Arch Linux machine. I installed all [necessary dependencies](https://www.mbari.org/products/research-software/mb-system/how-to-download-and-install-mb-system/#toggle-id-4) and have the package `libtirpc` installed.
When running the `configure` script, it ends with:

```
checking rpc/rpc.h usability... no
checking rpc/rpc.h presence... no
checking for rpc/rpc.h... no
checking tirpc/rpc/rpc.h usability... no
checking tirpc/rpc/rpc.h presence... no
checking for tirpc/rpc/rpc.h... no
checking rpc/types.h usability... no
checking rpc/types.h presence... no
checking for rpc/types.h... no
checking tirpc/rpc/types.h usability... no
checking tirpc/rpc/types.h presence... no
checking for tirpc/rpc/types.h... no
configure: error: Required header <rpc/types.h> not found, check include path and installed development packages
```

despite all files being in place:

```
ls /usr/include/tirpc/rpc
auth_des.h   clnt.h       des.h       pmap_clnt.h  rpc          rpc_com.h  rpcsec_gss.h    svc.h      xdr.h
auth_gss.h   clnt_soc.h   key_prot.h  pmap_prot.h  rpcb_clnt.h  rpcent.h   svc_auth_gss.h  svc_mt.h
auth.h       clnt_stat.h  netdb.h     pmap_rmt.h   rpcb_prot.h  rpc.h      svc_auth.h      svc_soc.h
auth_unix.h  des_crypt.h  nettype.h   raw.h        rpcb_prot.x  rpc_msg.h  svc_dg.h        types.h
```

I tried the following things with no effect (same error message, all usability/presence messages return "no")

1. Creating a symlinks to `tirpc/rpc` in `/usr/include` in case it's looking in the wrong folder
2. Editing the `configure` file to make sure the rpc dir is included, as described in this [similar issue](https://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/Ob5WL6zw/cygwin-configure-error-required-header-rpc-types-h-not-found) from another program using rpc
3. Changing the `#include` commands in MB-system's sourcefiles, but obviously that doesn't work since the error happens in the configure step

I don't know how to approach this issue further and would appreciate every hint.

Comment: 1. »» checking tirpc/rpc/rpc.h presence... no «« : Seems you are missing `libtirpc` ... 2. `rpc/rpc.h` is provided by glibc.

Comment: `libtirpc` is installed, see my second sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> checking rpc/rpc.h presence... no

All major "Linux OS" have the old Oracle etc. rpc headers `/usr/include/rpc/{17 headers}` provided by glibc / glibc-devel / libc6-dev. Arch bug report https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/62561 ... Might be missing in Arch, Manjaro etc. Arch clones because Arch is announced as a lightweight OS ?

A quick / safe fix : Get the headers from any glibc (-devel) package e.g. ftp://ftp.slackware.org.uk/slackware/slackware64-14.2/slackware64/l/glibc-2.23-x86_64-1.txz

```
tar xvf glibc-2.23-x86_64-1.txz
cd /usr/include/rpc/
# cp [path-to-rpc/-with-17-headers]/rpc/* ./
```

MB-System build prerequisites `# pacman -S openmotif graphicsmagick blas gdal netcdf proj cmake`

( gmt-6.0.0 was built manually with `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../` )

```
git clone https://github.com/dwcaress/MB-System.git
cd MB-System/ && ./configure && make 
# make install
          // No errors
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll try it tomorrow and provide feedback, thanks!

Comment: Just got the same problem on ubuntu 20.04 - and this fixed my issue - I had to use the exact same version of the Slackware file you pointed 'glibc-2.23-x86_64-1.txz' (  newer version did not include all the headers)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/alekseyzimin/masurca/issues/69) issue may be of some help.
It adds `-ltirpc` to `LDFLAGS` and `-I/usr/include/tirpc` to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Link only answers get deleted.  Please post the essentials of the answer here, so that it is obvious it is correct.